# Вывод новостей на главной, как поставить количество выводимых новостей?

Tags: php, kohana

Вывожу на главной странице сайта новости из разделов *новости* и из подкатегорий раздела *новости*.

Сделал дополнительный блок для вывода.

В шаблоне код:

```
<?php foreach ($block_1 as $news_1):?>
тут новости со стилями и т.д
<?php endforeach?>
```

в контроллере главной application\classes\controller
index.php

код для блока:

```
$this->template->categories = $data;
$this->template->block_1 = ORM::factory('news')->where('status', '=',
 1)->order_by('id', 'DESC')->and_where('block1', '=',
 1)->limit(10)->find_all();
```

Как в `limit(10)` вывести значение из админки (значение количества новостей показывать на главной)?

В "админке", в настройках сделал поле `per_page_block1`, в таблице *settings*.

Пытаюсь через админку задавать лимит на вывод новостей на главной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получайте значение `per_page_block1` с помощью SQL запроса и подставляйте его в `limit()`

```
$per_page_block1 = DB::select(...)->from('settings')->where(...)->execute()->get('...'); // условия запроса придумайте сами

$this->template->block_1 = ORM::factory('news')->where('status', '=',
 1)->order_by('id', 'DESC')->and_where('block1', '=',
 1)->limit($per_page_block1)->find_all();
```